# Total effect of main variable and it's interaction with dummy

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, interaction, regression-coefficients

I am going to estimate the following model:

y=constant+b1(X)+b2(X)(Dummy)

We have daily data from 1990 to 2000. Dummy variable is equal to one for the daily data of year 2000, else zero. b1 is the main effect, and b2 is the marginal effect because of the dummy. The total effect in year 2000= b1+b2. How to estimate the statistical significance for this total effect (b1+b2), will we use F-stat or t-stat? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there not a main effect of Dummy in the model? There is only an interaction with X? You should generally include lower-order terms in a regression that has higher-order terms in it.

Comment: Thank you, we are not interested in the simple effect of dummy. We are more interested that what is the incremental effect of when interacted with dummy, and whether total effect (b1+b2) is statistically significant or not. For example incremental beta (b2) is 0.20 but b1 is -0.15 then the sum of b1 +b2=0.20 -0.150= .05. So we can say that the incremental effect due to dummy is negative but total effect is positive; however, we dnt know if it the total effect is significant or not?

Comment: Just because you are not interested in it doesn't mean you should exclude it in the model. If it isn't there when it should be, your estimates will be messed up. I'll write an answer assuming you include it (which you should).

Comment: Thank you Noah :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a term for the dummy in your regression so that your model looks like the following:

$$E[Y|X] = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 D + \beta_3 XD$$

In this model, $\beta_1$ is the effect of $X$ on $Y$ when $D$ is zero, i.e., in years other than 2000. $\beta_2$ is the effect of $D$ on $Y$ when $X = 0$. It may be the case that $X=0$ is an uninteresting or impossible value, in which case you don't have to interpret $\beta_2$. You still need to include it in your model. $\beta_3$ is the difference between the effect of $X$ on $Y$ when $D = 1$ and when $D=0$. It is the coefficient on interaction term, and if it is significant, you have evidence that the effect of $X$ depends on whether the year is 2000 or not.

You are asking about $\beta_1 + \beta_3$. This is the effect of $X$ on $Y$ when $D=1$ (i.e., the effect of $X$ in the year 2000). There are two ways to test whether this value is significant. The first, and easier method, is simply to replace $D$ with $D'=1-D$ and rerun the regression. Now, $\beta_1$ is the effect of $X$ when $D'=0$, or equivalently, when $D=1$. The test of significance on $\beta_1$ in this regression is a test of whether the effect of $X$ on $Y$ in the year 2000 is different from zero.

The second way is to use contrasts. Extract the variance-covariance matrix of the estimated parameters in the original model (with $D$, not $D'$), $\hat \Sigma$ from the regression model and set up a contrast matrix $a = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$. Compute $\sqrt{a\hat \Sigma a'}$. This value is the standard error of $\beta_1 + \beta_3$, which you can use in the t-statistic formula to perform a t-test. If done properly, both methods will yield equivalent answers.

Comment: Thank you very much Noah, I have tried it and I got the same answers using both ways. Previously, I tried square root of F-test and those t-stats are also same as  obtained by these two methods. I guess square root of F might not work whee we have to sum more than two effects.